# How to make href works in icon

Tags: html, href

Hi i have issue with link.. I need wrap magnifier icon with href and make active the link in new tab if i click on the magnifier icon.
[image] Grateful for some advice.

```
   <div class="folio-thumb"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/plochyostravamin.jpg" alt="image" /><a href="http://www.plochyostrava.cz" target="_blank">**<div class="icon-zoom"></div></a></div>
```

Comment: And what's your "issue"?  What isn't working?

Comment: when i click on the icon nothing happen but i dont know why

Answer (score 2):

Move the opening `a` tag so it surrounds the image

```
 <div class="folio-thumb"><a href="http://www.plochyostrava.cz" target="_blank"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/plochyostravamin.jpg" alt="image" /><div class="icon-zoom"></div></a></div>
```